# How do I select an element in dropdown div menu in Selenium WebDriver? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to select a specific option in a dropdown menu but haven't been able to do so. When inspecting the web page, I haven't been able to open the menu to see if there's any xpath to a specific path I could use. The web in question is https://megatlon.com/clases , I'm trying to select another gym other than Megatlon Alcorta. Let's suppose Megatlon Barracas. The following line helped me open the menu but that's as far as I could get:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div').click()`

How can I select another option and leave the dropdown menu? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div').click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(),"Megatlon Barrio Jardín (Córdoba)")]'))).click()
```

Click the dropdown, wait for visibility and then click on the text you want